# ElementNotInteractable Exception because of Chatbot toggle selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, exception

We have recently integrated a chat bot application in our website and it does not have a minimize or close button. It will overlap in all of the pages after login. So once after login because of this, when trying to click any element it throws error as Element not interactable. Is there any way to handle this like disabling this using Javascript?
[image]

I tried to Hide the chat badge using javascript and try to perform actions still It's throwing element Not interactable error.

```
WebElement chatPill = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='fc_frame']"));
        System.out.println("execution started");
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display:none')",chatPill);
//        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','z-index:-100')",chatPill);
        System.out.println("Script execution Completed - chat box Hidden");
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'sidebar-menu')]/a[text()='Employees']")));

    
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[text()='Reports']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Reports']")).click();
```

Console Logs:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.105)
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:19.891Z'
System info: host: 'LetsVentures-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.29.225', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.5', java.version: '11.0.5'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 84.0.4147.105, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0..., userDataDir: /var/folders/vd/4xltw6c51_j...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:59011}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 34e18768d41e130605a9cd5ef800ac71
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:276)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
    at resources.chatBoxHiding.main(chatBoxHiding.java:41)
```

Comment: include the full exception you are receiving here.

Comment: @pcalkins I have updated with full the error message

Comment: seems to be a click action that is causing this.  I don't think it has anything to do with the chat element.  (You'd get a click intercepted exception for that...)  Include the code with the .click()

Comment: @pcalkins Updated the click action too. But If the chat element is not there, click action is performing fine. Only if the chat element comes, the click actions are getting interupted

Comment: if the exception is still "Element not interactable" try adding a webdriver wait to wait for the expected condition of clickable.  If the chat box were stealing the click you'd see an exception that says "another element would receive the click", and it would list the element that would receive the click.